# TypeScript - How to append line break (\n) on string?

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I'm trying to concatenate a string with a "\n" like this:

```
- Item 1
- Item 2
```

```
var msg: string = '';
msg += '- Campo NOME é obrigatório';
msg += "\n- Campo EMAIL é obrigatório";
```

But the output comes without the line break:

```
- Item 1 - Item 2
```

I searched a lot about it but I didn't find a solution. Could you please help me? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you rendering to HTML, you will want to use the HTML tag for a newline :

The string `Hello\n\nTest` in your source will look like this:

```
Hello!

Test
```

The string `Hello<br><br>Test` will look like this in HTML source:

```
Hello<br><br>Test
```

**Try this :**

```
var msg: string = "";
msg += "- Campo NOME é obrigatório";
msg += "<br/>- Campo EMAIL é obrigatório";
```

Here is fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9fuxgbms/1/

Comment: This does not work for me. My versions are - 
Angular CLI: 9.0.6
Node: 10.15.2

Answer (score 0):

I am using Angular 15 and this works for me,

home.component.ts

```
headerText = "Hi, Enter Your \n Name";
```

home.component.html

```
<div class="header">
  <h1>{{headerText}}</h1>
</div>
```

home.component.scss

```
.header {
    margin-top: 100px;

    h1 {
      white-space: break-spaces; // <===== This is important
    }
  }
```

You can use `white-space: break-spaces;` or `white-space: pre-line;` depending on your usage.